# Powershell Rename File to Original Filename

Tags: windows, powershell, filenames, powershell-3.0

Ok so I have a script:

```
gc .\oauthrn.cms |
    % {
        $a=@();
        $b="";
        $a += $_.split('|'); 
        for ($i=0;$i -lt 168; $i++) 
        {
            $b += $a[$i] + '|'
        } 
        $b
    } |
    % {
        $_.TrimEnd("|")
    } |
    out-file "H:\Documentation\Scripts\Pipe Delimiter Project\ShineyNewFile.txt" -encoding ASCII

gc .\oauthrn1.cms |
    % {
        $a=@();
        $b="";
        $a += $_.split('|'); 
        for ($i=0;$i -lt 168; $i++) 
        {
            $b += $a[$i] + '|'
        } 
        $b
    } |
    % {
        $_.TrimEnd("|")
    } |
    out-file "H:\Documentation\Scripts\Pipe Delimiter Project\ShineyNewFile1.txt" -encoding ASCII
```

**Problem**

So basically I would like to rename the file the original name, but when I name the `ShineyNewFile`, `oauthrn`, it doesn't output anything in the file.

I imagine it's because it's still looking at that file to output during the `out-file` statement...

Does anyone have any insight on this? Is my assumption correct? Is there some way to handle this keeping the syntax I am currently using? I am new to `powershell`, but it is a great tool.

Comment: Could you please describe what you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: "So basically I would like to rename the file the original name, but when I name the ShineyNewFile, oauthrn, it doesn't output anything in the file. "

Comment: Yea we can read, but it still doesn't make sense. You can just `Rename-item ShineyNewFile.txt oauthrn.cms`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm not sure why you have most of that in the script since the TrimEnd gets rid of all the extra pipe characters from the last question you asked that I saw, but anyway, does this do what you want?

```
gc .\oauthrn.cms |
    % {$_.TrimEnd("|")} |
    out-file "H:\Documentation\Scripts\Pipe Delimiter Project\ShineyNewFile.txt" -encoding ascii
Rename-Item "H:\Documentation\Scripts\Pipe Delimiter Project\ShineyNewFile.txt" "oauthrn.cms"

gc .\oauthrn1.cms |
    % {$_.TrimEnd("|")} |
    out-file "H:\Documentation\Scripts\Pipe Delimiter Project\ShineyNewFile1.txt" -encoding ascii
Rename-Item "H:\Documentation\Scripts\Pipe Delimiter Project\ShineyNewFile1.txt" "oauthrn1.cms"
```

Comment: What are you not sure of? I basically just added it a second time for another file, this process has to do the same manipulation to two files. I'm not sure what trimming the last pipe off the end of each line has to do with renaming the file...yea it does exactly what i want. I guess I'm mostly unsure of syntax oppose to functions...thanks again.

Comment: What I'm not sure of is the whole `$a` and `$b` part with splitting and manually re-joining it all. It looked like all you were doing was trimming the pipes off the end, which that one line does. Also, that whole `For($i=0` part could all be summed up with `$a[0..167] -join "|"` but that really isn't needed for the script.

Comment: I got an error: Out-File: A Positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Rename-item' @TheMadTechnician

Comment: Because that should be a different line. Rename-Item is it's own line, after the Out-File line. Do not put a pipe "|" after the Out-File command.

Comment: Ok, I got |out-file "H:\Documentation\Scripts\Pipe Delimiter Project\ShineyNewFile1.txt" -encoding ASCII 
 Rename-Item "H:\Documentation\Scripts\Pipe Delimiter Project\ShineyNewFile.txt" "oauthrn1.cms"

Comment: I get an error @TheMadTechnician - Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Comment: Add `-Force` to the last line to make it overwrite an existing file. Sorry, I didn't know it was in the same folder, I thought you were outputting to a new folder.

Comment: I did this Rename-Item "H:\Documentation\Scripts\Pipe Delimiter Project\ShineyNewFile.txt" "oauthrn1.cms" -force and it says it cannot create file when that file already exists. Do I need to delete the file first?

Comment: That would solve the problem. You really don't need to ask though, try it and see if it works.

Comment: YOU RIGHT YOU RIGHT. I got it!